# Designing modular application with meteor

Tags: meteor

I will develop a modular application something like for example:

in one side a fomular designer (you can create a wysiwyg form designer like wufoo)
in other side a form filer (store data)
and other data exploration.

( It is just an example )

In my mind I would like to create three meteor applications and use Meteor.connect to interconnect all.
Like that each application will be independant (except for the connect part (just few data)).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend building them as separate smart packages, and adding dependencies inside the package.js files. See the [git repository](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages) for examples.